# Fall of black pixels in a Quadtree

Tags: c, quadtree

Hello I am trying to create a function Gravity that make all the black pixels of a Quadtree to "fall" if they can (if there is a white pixel under).
for instance Gravity(Qt1) gives Qt2 :
[image: Qt1 | Qt2]

The Quadtree class:

```
typedef struct Qtree{
    bool allblack;
    struct Qtree * son[4];
}Qtree;
```

I have made some auxiliariy functions:
**create a black pixel**

```
Qtree* create_Black(){
    Qtree* I -> malloc(sizeof(Qtree));
    I->son[0] = I->son[1] = I->son[2] = I->son[3] = NULL
    return I;
```

**create a white pixel**

```
Qtree* create_White(){ 
    return NULL;
```

**create a Qtree** based on 4 sons

```
Qtree* create_Comp(Qtree* i0, Qtree* i1, Qtree* i2, Qtree i3){         
    Qtree* I = malloc(sizeof(Qtree));         
    I->son[0] = i0;         
    ...         
    return I;
}
```

I already have done some code that exchanges black pixel but I can obtain the result wanted :(
If some guys could help me, I can't find any ressources on internet

Comment: I really don't get both `create_black` and `create_white`. How would you represent an image (let say your left example) with such a quadtree ?

Comment: There are several kind of quadtree, depending on the application. But none for which your functions make sense to me.